# Why does Scapy Raw payload adds unexpected bytes when payload size is greater then 127 characters?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string of chars stored in a variable called 'value'. This string is basically a list of numbers from 0 to 255. I use this as a payload to a Scapy packet (below). Notice that in the variable 'value,' the byte \x7f is followed by \x80, \0x81, and so on. However, in the Scapy Raw payload, the \xc2 character is replicated between character after \x7f (please see below). Why is the \xc2 being added?

> > > value
> > >       '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬\xad®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
> > >       rawpacket = Raw(load=value)
> > >       rawpacket
> > >       <Raw  load='\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\xc2\x80\xc2\x81\xc2\x82\xc2\x83\xc2\x84\xc2\x85\xc2\x86\xc2\x87\xc2\x88\xc2\x89\xc2\x8a\xc2\x8b\xc2\x8c\xc2\x8d\xc2\x8e\xc2\x8f\xc2\x90\xc2\x91\xc2\x92\xc2\x93\xc2\x94\xc2\x95\xc2\x96\xc2\x97\xc2\x98\xc2\x99\xc2\x9a\xc2\x9b\xc2\x9c\xc2\x9d\xc2\x9e\xc2\x9f\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa1\xc2\xa2\xc2\xa3\xc2\xa4\xc2\xa5\xc2\xa6\xc2\xa7\xc2\xa8\xc2\xa9\xc2\xaa\xc2\xab\xc2\xac\xc2\xad\xc2\xae\xc2\xaf\xc2\xb0\xc2\xb1\xc2\xb2\xc2\xb3\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb5\xc2\xb6\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb8\xc2\xb9\xc2\xba\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbc\xc2\xbd\xc2\xbe\xc2\xbf\xc3\x80\xc3\x81\xc3\x82\xc3\x83\xc3\x84\xc3\x85\xc3\x86\xc3\x87\xc3\x88\xc3\x89\xc3\x8a\xc3\x8b\xc3\x8c\xc3\x8d\xc3\x8e\xc3\x8f\xc3\x90\xc3\x91\xc3\x92\xc3\x93\xc3\x94\xc3\x95\xc3\x96\xc3\x97\xc3\x98\xc3\x99\xc3\x9a\xc3\x9b\xc3\x9c\xc3\x9d\xc3\x9e\xc3\x9f\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa2\xc3\xa3\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa6\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa8\xc3\xa9\xc3\xaa\xc3\xab\xc3\xac\xc3\xad\xc3\xae\xc3\xaf\xc3\xb0\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb2\xc3\xb3\xc3\xb4\xc3\xb5\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb7\xc3\xb8\xc3\xb9\xc3\xba\xc3\xbb\xc3\xbc\xc3\xbd\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbf' |>

Comment: how can I prevent Raw from adding the \xc2 character?

Comment: If you are on PY3, remember to use the byte tag before your string `b"\x01"`

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar problem. tag `b` solved the problem.

```py
data = b'\x00\x01\xff ...'
```

Comment: `b` is not tag, it's prefix to create [bytes objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)